# How can both Gaussian and salt & pepper noise be removed from an image?

Tags: image-processing, filters, noise

An image is corrupted by Gaussian noise,then salt & pepper noise. How can you eliminate it and why?

Comment: Got an example?

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you looked at so far?

Comment: if i had salt and pepper infected image and then i blurr it with gaussian noise can i restore it?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest approach: First apply [Median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) for salt and pepper noise, and then use [Gaussian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) to eliminate Gaussian noise.

Answer (score 7):

[Median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) is very effective to remove salt & pepper noise. After median filtering you need to use a [Image Denoising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_denoising) method to remove Gaussian Noise.

There are many image denoising methods(for more see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_denoising)). Some of them are

[Gaussian Scale Mixture](http://decsai.ugr.es/~javier/denoise/) algorithm.

Non Local Means method proposed by Buades et al.([pdf](http://bengal.missouri.edu/~kes25c/nl2.pdf))